# Am I authorized to create a database based on screenshots of Baldur's Gate?

Tags: baldurs-gate, infinity-engine

I would like to create a database of all text of the Baldur's Gate game. NPC dialog but also item descriptions and journal. I know how to use the tool [NearInfinity](https://github.com/NearInfinityBrowser/NearInfinity) but I don't want to use it for this project as I don't know if I have authorization to do so.

I would like to create a database of all PC and NPC base on screenshot of in game dialog and generate the voice of this dialog using new IA voice based technologies. I already tested the system and it work.

My objective is not to create a mod here. I just want to create assets. I need to get more detail about what I'm authorized to do also.

Can I simply create a Repository of image and sound on GitHub?

Comment: I think this is more of a law question, with a few tweaks to focus on the law rather than legal advice.

Comment: What did Bioware say when you asked them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it about legality of a derivative work.

Comment: [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) has many questions tagged [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright); one may be of use.

Answer (score 5):

To get authorisation to do this, contact Bioware and get permission. Realistically though, you're unlikely to get a response, much less permission.

Generating sound files from the text, either with AI or by recording yourself reading them would be considered a Derivative Work. Creating a derivative work requires the copyright holder's (either Bioware or EA since EA owns them) permission.

You could, of course, do this anyway and hope EA won't notice and/or care. This depends on how you plan to use the assets- incorporating them into you and your friends' DnD campaign will cause no issues whereas selling them might.

Comment: Agree. It really depends on how the asset will be used. I remember this (somewhat rough) discussion of IP assets vs. brands from the FAQ for I Wanna Be The Guy: https://iwbtg.kayin.moe/faq.html (under the "Intellectual Property" tab)